# Weighted bevel causing artifacts inside a cylinder

Tags: bevel, artifacts

My bevels on the revolver's cylinder causes artifacts or stretching inside the other 5 holes that are cylinders. I have tried to use loop cuts, using the knife tool but it doesn't seem to work. I am just wondering that can I do anything about this. I don't mind if I can't get it fixed because I think it is just a really small detail. I have circled the artifacts on the pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please help me if you can, thank you.

Edit:
This is what I wanted my model to look originally with a bevel right here.
[image]
[image]

Also I just realized.. Why does the bevel act like this here from the same spot??. Didn't actually notice it before because the detail is so tiny.
[image]

Comment: Loopcuts should help. How exactly did you try them?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is (only) the bevel causing problems, since it looks like there is also a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on the model. But pardon me for not trying to recreate that model all by myself to find ways for optimizing...

Answer (score 1):

I will use the answer template, as the comments dont have any image attachment mechanism.
The topology shown above is bad for different resons:[image]

First, you have a bunch of very streched  polygons, which is always problematic. In this particular case the problem is that the bevel will very quickly cause an overlap due to the very thin dimension ( i just highlited (highlit?) a couple of them).
Here is a topological solution to this:
[image]

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Sorry that I haven't answered in over a month. The thing is I forgot what site I posted this thread on.... sooo I finally found it just because I searching on google "weighted bevel artifacts" and my thread was on the first page lol. Soooo yeah mb.

Comment: I tried cleaning up the topology to see if it would fix but no so i just didn't finish fixing the topology all around the cylinder. The problem still exists that annoys me. The shading error inside the cylinder holes. If i modeled my model the same way i see in the picture. Yes it would solve the problem but I am stubborn and I wanna somewhat stay true to my refrences. I will add one more picture to show you what I really wanted at the beginning.